# Sketching sets of complex numbers, e.g. $z=i$

Tags: geometry, inequality, complex-numbers

> Sketch the following sets:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle M = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \left\lvert\frac{z+3i-4}{z+6}\right\rvert \leq 1, z\neq -6\right\}$
> 2. $\displaystyle N= \left\{z \in \mathbb{C}: z^3-i=0\right\}$

(1) I wrote for $z= x+iy$ and used that in the fracture. After that I multiplied the fracture with the complex conjugate to get the $i$ out of the denominator. But then my number got really long: $\frac{(x^2+2x-24+y^2+3y)-i((xy-4y)-(18+3x+6y+xy))}{(6+x)^2+y^2}$. Although I could separate it into the real part and the imaginary part now. I don't think my way seems to be right.

Could you point me to the right direction.

(2) $z^3-i=0 \Leftrightarrow z^3 = i \Leftrightarrow(x+iy)^3=i \Rightarrow x=0 \land y=1$.  So that means $z=i.$ So that would mean that $Re(z) =0$ and $Im(z)=1$. But wouldn't that mean that there would be only one point in set $N$?

Another question from another exercise. I calculated the complex number and got as a result: $z=-1024-i1024$. So the $Re(z)=-1024$, but is $Im(z)= -1024$ or $Im(z)= 1024$? I thought it should be $Im(z)= -1024$ since $z$ is defined as $z=x+iy$. Is this correct?

Comment: @k.stm thanks for pointing it out. just edited it.

Comment: Yes, for $z=-1024-1024i$, its imaginary part is $\operatorname{Im}(z)=-1024$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that$$\left\lvert\frac{z+3i-4}{z+6}\right\rvert\leqslant1\iff\lvert z+3i-4\rvert\leqslant\lvert z+6\rvert.$$So, it's the half-plane whose elements are the points of $\mathbb C$ which are closer to $4-3i$ than to $-6$.

And the second set consists of the three cube roots of $i=e^{\pi i/2}$, which are$$e^{\pi i/6},\ e^{5\pi i/6}\text{, and }e^{3\pi i/2}.$$

Comment: How did you get: $i=e^{\pi i/2}$

Comment: Because$$i=0+1\times i=\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)i=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}2\right).$$

Comment: For 1) $\left\lvert\frac{z+3i-4}{z+6}\right\rvert\leqslant1\iff\lvert z+3i-4\rvert\leqslant\lvert z+6\rvert \iff \lvert x+iy+3i-4\rvert \leq \lvert x+iy+6 \rvert \iff \sqrt{(x-4)^2+(3+y)^2} \leq \sqrt{(6+x)^2+y^2} \iff ..... \iff 0 \leq 20x + 6y + 11$.

Comment: So I drew the line for $y= -\frac{10}{3}x - \frac{11}{6}$. Everything that is on the line and the right of it are in my set.

Is this correct?

Comment: For 2) you used Euler's equation. So how do I sketch $z_1=e^{\pi i/6},z_2 = \ e^{5\pi i/6}\text{, and } z_3 = e^{3\pi i/2}$. To my understanding they should be three points on the circle with the radius $1$.

Comment: The line that you should have obtained (I did not check your computations) is the perpendicular of the segmen that joins $4-3i$ to $-6$. Then you take the half-plane to which $4-4i$ belongs.

Comment: And, yes, I got three points from the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

After you multiply the fracture with its complex conjugate,

$$ \frac{(x+iy+3i-4)(x-iy-3i-4)}{(x+iy+6)(x-iy+6)} \leq 1$$
you should get,
$$ \frac{x^2+y^2-6y-8x+25}{x^2+y^2+12x+36} \leq 1 \implies 20x+6y+9\ge 1$$

So, the set lies in the upper-right of the plane above the line $20x+6y+9=0$.